# Multiple JSON File calls in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

does anyone have an idea how can i call all these json files together?
I am currently learning swift and would like to dedicate myself to json.
I will be grateful for any help.
this is my code:

ContentView:

```
import SwiftUI



 struct ContentView: View {



@State var surahs: [SurahElement] = Bundle.main.decode("surah.json")


 @State var ayats: [Surah] = Bundle.main.decode("surah_1.json")

var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
        List(surahs){ item in
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(ayats: self.ayats[0])){
            HStack{
                Text(item.title)
                    Spacer()
                Text(item.titleAr)
            }
        }
      }
}
}
 }

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
}
}
```

DetailView:

```
import SwiftUI



struct DetailView: View {

var ayats: Surah

func verseNumber() {
    var n = Int.random(in: 1...7)
     n += 1
}
var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .center){
        Text(self.ayats.name)

        VStack{
            Text(self.ayats.verse.verse1)
            Text(self.ayats.verse.verse2)
            Text(self.ayats.verse.verse3)
            Text(self.ayats.verse.verse4)
            Text(self.ayats.verse.verse5)
            Text(self.ayats.verse.verse6)
            Text(self.ayats.verse.verse7)

        }

    }



}
}

struct DetailView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static let ayats: [Surah] = Bundle.main.decode("surah_1.json")
static var previews: some View {
    DetailView(ayats: ayats[0])
}
}
```

sorry i couldn't post json file

I got the json data from hier  https://github.com/semarketir/quranjson

und more json ....
in this work there is more json data, the only difference is the verse.
my problem is how do i go on?

Comment: Can you clarify “ call all these json files together” thanks

Comment: I have collected all json files in one, because otherwise I have to call up several json then the code is not usual

Answer (score 0):

I have collected all json files in one, because otherwise I have to call up several json then the code is not usual.

Answer (score 0):

```
    {
    "place": "Mecca",
    "type": "Makkiyah",
    "count": 7,
    "title": "Al-Fatiha",
    "titleAr":"الفاتحة",
    "index": "001",
    "pages": "1",
    "juz": [
        {
            "index": "01",
            "verse": {
                "start": "verse_1",
                "end": "verse_7"
            }
        }
    ]
},
```

This is the first json

```
{
"index": "001",
"name": "al-Fatihah",
"verse": {

    "verse_0": "﻿بِسْمِ ٱللَّهِ ٱلرَّحْمَٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ",
    "verse_1": "ٱلْحَمْدُ لِلَّهِ رَبِّ ٱلْعَٰلَمِينَ",
    "verse_2": "ٱلرَّحْمَٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ",
    "verse_3": "مَٰلِكِ يَوْمِ ٱلدِّينِ",
    "verse_4": "إِيَّاكَ نَعْبُدُ وَإِيَّاكَ نَسْتَعِينُ",
    "verse_5": "ٱهْدِنَا ٱلصِّرَٰطَ ٱلْمُسْتَقِيمَ",
    "verse_6": "صِرَٰطَ ٱلَّذِينَ أَنْعَمْتَ عَلَيْهِمْ غَيْرِ ٱلْمَغْضُوبِ عَلَيْهِمْ وَلَا ٱلضَّآلِّينَ"
},
"count": 7,
"juz": [
    {
        "index": "01",
        "verse": {
            "start": "verse_1",
            "end": "verse_7"
        }
    }
]
},
```

This is the second json
that was how you see on https://github.com/semarketir/quranjson more json,
this made it easier to call